# Flash Of Unstyled Text (FOUT) on reload using next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, sass

We have used multiple fonts in our sites, but one we are loading pages it will changes font one (Bebas Neue) to the another font(Poppins). So, i need a solution to stop flickering between two fonts.

[image]

I did R&D but didn't found any solutions.

Comment: This article might help you https://www.paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/

Comment: Can you please let me know if my answer is helpful in any way, else I can delete it?